Is there a criterion for extension of map to continuous map over triples of geodesics on compact Riemann surface?
Consider $X=X_1\times X_2\times X_3$ a set of triples for some finite non-empty sets  $X_1,X_2,X_3$ of closed geodesics on some compact Riemann surface $\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{O}$ topology (set of open sets) on $X$. Denote by $(X,\mathcal{O})$ the resulting topological space.
Denote for any $S\subset X$ by $S_1:=\lbrace s\,|\,\exists\, (s,r,t)\in S\,\rbrace$, i.e, the set of first components of triples in $S$, and analogously $S_2$ and $S_3$. We define $\Omega(S)$ with $\Omega(S)=S_1\times S_2\times S_3$. Assume that there is a non-empty set $I\subset X$ such that
$$\mathcal{B}=\lbrace \lbrace (\phi,\psi,\rho)\rbrace \,| \,(\phi,\psi,\rho)\in\Omega(I)\text{ with }\mathrm{im}(\phi)\cap \mathrm{im}(\psi)\cap \mathrm{im}(\rho) \neq \emptyset\,\rbrace\subset \mathcal{O}$$
is a basis of $\mathcal{O}$. Assume also that $|\mathcal{B}|$ is of size $C\, |I|^2$ for some constant $C>0$.
Finally, I know that I have the same structure on another topology $\mathcal{O}'$ over $X$ with corresponding sets $I'$ and basis $\mathcal{B}'$ over $\Omega(I')$ as defined for $\mathcal{B}$, and $|\mathcal{B}'|$ is of size $C'\,|I'|^2$ for some constant $C'>0$. I am trying to make claims (e.g. concerning continuity) about maps $\pi:(X,\mathcal{O})\to (X,\mathcal{O}')$ for which I have information only on the set $I$ and $I'$. In particular, I have given that $\pi^{-1}(I')=I$.
Is there a way, using the fact that the underlying structure is a Riemann surface, to extend $\pi^{-1}(I')=I$ to $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}')=\mathcal{B}$, which would imply continuity ? I tried "thickening" the geodesics by some $\varepsilon$ band to open sets in $\Sigma$ in such a way that they basically preserve the form of $\mathcal{B}$, which would make $(X,\mathcal{O})$ related to the product topology of $\Sigma\times\Sigma\times\Sigma$. But this implies a switch from a finite topological space $(X,\mathcal{O})$ to some subspace of $\Sigma\times\Sigma\times\Sigma$, which is not finite, and here I get stuck.

The question is very unclearly written. Part of the problem is that you are explaining standard things and do not explain nonstandard ones. For starters, you did not explain what topology on the set of geodesics you are using. It is a finite set. Do you use the discrete topology?

I rewrite it, sorry for the confusion.
